# Hibernate inheritance - OneToMany with 2 class that extend parent not work

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I have 3 Entities:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor 
@Entity 
@Table(name = "beneficiary") 
@Inheritance 
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, name = "type") 
public abstract class Beneficiary {   
    public Beneficiary() {}

      @Id private String id;

      private String description; 
}


@Data
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("company")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class BeneficiaryCompany extends Beneficiary {
  public BeneficiaryCompany() {
    super();
  }

  public BeneficiaryCompany(String id, String description) {
    super(id, description);
  }
}


@Data
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("person")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class BeneficiaryPerson extends Beneficiary {
  public BeneficiaryPerson() {}

  public BeneficiaryPerson(String id, String description) {
    super(id, description);
  }
}
```

An in the other class I want to have 2 separate collections:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {

  public Transaction() {}

  @Id private String id;

  private String description;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = BeneficiaryCompany.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", nullable = false)
  private Set<BeneficiaryCompany> beneficiaryCompanies;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,targetEntity = BeneficiaryPerson.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", nullable = false)
  private Set<BeneficiaryPerson> beneficiaryPeople;
}
```

The problem is that every Beneficiary was fetched into beneficiaryCompanies, and beneficiaryPeople in the debugger tells me that:

> Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw
>   'org.hibernate.WrongClassException' exception.

The database records looks fine (DiscriminatorColumn was created). What could be the problem? Why beneficiaryCompanies contains BeneficiaryPerson objects?

@EDIT:
To fetch the records I am using SpringData JPA repositories.

Comment: Try removing @Entity  from your abstract class as a start. Ity is not an entity.

Comment: @Alexandar Are you sure I should remove it? https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-entity-inheritance-with-jpa-and-hibernate/
I found it, maybe not exactly what I have got (ex. different Inheritance type), but Vlad uses Entity. The second question is when I use Entity - then got  No identifier specified for entity: BeneficiaryCompany

Comment: yes I am sure. In his case the superclass is not abstract therefore it is a valid entity. In your case it is abstract therefore it is not. It can never be instancieted alone.

Comment: So is it still not working _

Comment: Yes, unfortunately still the same

Comment: Hibernate has a problem when you have two @OneToMany relationships to the same entity (or similar entity, as both of your entities have the same base class) - maybe you can start searching with this knowledge: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860781/hibernate-jpa-multiple-onetomany-for-same-model

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this? It's still a problem in 2024.

Answer (score 3):

> Use `@MappedSuperclass` on your base class `Beneficiary`

Alexandar Petrov is absolutely correct. You have to remove `@Entity` because superclass is not an entity. When dealing with inheritance extending a class, you can use `@MappedSuperclass` annotation on the base class, in your case, it is `Beneficiary`.

Edit:
[This](https://thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/) is a very good article you can refer to.

Comment: As I read, I cannot use only one table to store my entities and distinguish subclasses using hibernate (or I am wrong?). I did not mention that in my question. For now I can try use Inheritance annotation and look for some other solution, but if I do not find solution, I will use MappedSuperclass. Thanks for reply :)

Comment: It depends on how you imagine your end result. Please share your desired DDL and I will do my best to help you.

Comment: I will simplify it a little (describe only a few columns). I want to have one table, that contains data like
ID, transactionId, startDate, beneficiaryType - these values are used by BeneficiaryPerson and BeneficiaryCompany.
This table contains the personId used only by BeneficiaryPerson (for BeneficiaryCompany in the table is set to null),
CompanyDescription for BeneficiaryCompany - BeneficiaryPerson has this value set to null.

So - I want only one table - easier maintenance for DB developers (and much more reasons, I have no influence on it).

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-the-discriminatorcolumn-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I think I have implemented that in my question post - however, the problem is that in class Transaction I have got 2 OneToMany sets, and every record, even if is not BeneficiaryCompany (BeneficiaryPerson for example) - it goes to BeneficiaryCompany set (and the BeneficiaryPerson set throws exception described in my question). I do not know it is Hibernate bug, or I just have done stupid mistake. Anyway, thank you very much for the answer Ilya!

Answer (score 0):

Add `@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)` to `Beneficiary` class. This will force Hibernate to use the discriminator when it fetches the collections.